# Почему в консоль выводит "undefined". Это функция по нахождению периметра треугольника

Tags: javascript

```js
function per(a, b, c) {

  a + b + c

  return
}

const secondResult = per(4, 3, 2, 5)

console.log(secondResult)
```

Comment: `undefined` возвращается потому что именно его вы и возвращаете в строке `return }`. читайте https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics#vozvrat-znacheniya

Comment: Всё ровно, выводит "undefined"

Comment: @Denbez "Всё рaвно"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function per(a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c;
}

const secondResult = per(4, 3, 2, 5)
console.log(secondResult)
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Undefined выводится по той простой причине, что функция ничего не возвращает. В JS для того, чтобы сделать то, что было задумано, следует сделать так:

```js
 function per(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
 }
  
  const secondResult = per(4, 3, 2);
  console.log(secondResult);
```

Теперь мы возвращаем сумму трех сторон треугольника, а не пустоту. В вашем примере возвращается, можно сказать, ничто, а после этого это самое ничто и присваивается константе secondResult.