# Суть кода проверять элементы массива и выводить на экран сообщение

Tags: javascript

```
let arr = [4,3,2,6,7]

for (let i; i!=arr.length;i++) {
    if (arr[i] >= 0){
      alert('Все элементы массива положительные')
    }
    else{
      alert('Все элементы массива отрицательные')
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос непонятен, опишите условия подробнее. Почему при проверке одного элемента у вас выводится сообщение о виде всех элементов? И что делать, если часть элементов положительная, а часть отрицательная?

Comment: По подробней, задание звучит так: "Дано одномерный массив размерностью N.Сделать определенное сообщение, если массив включает себя только отрицательные или только положительные". По поводу "Что делать если есть и отрицательные и положительные" то просто вывести с помощью alert(Массив имеет отрицательные и положительные элементы)

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1292479

Comment: Да, и в правду забыл)

Comment: Еще, могут быть одни нули)

Comment: Я уже поставил .

Comment: Если одни нули то выводить ,что все элементы положительные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function checkArray(a) {
  if (arr.length == 0) {
    console.log('Array is empty');
    return;
  }
  let countP = 0;
  let countN = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
      countP++;
    } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
      countN++;
    }
  }
  if (countP == arr.length) {
    console.log('Все элементы массива положительные');
  } else if (countN == arr.length) {
    console.log('Все элементы массива отрицательные');
  }
}

let arr = [4, 3, 2, 6, 7];
checkArray(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё воспользоваться [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
function checkArray(array) {
  if (array.every(num => num >= 0)) alert('Все элементы массива положительные');
  else if(array.every(num => num < 0)) alert('Все элементы массива отрицательные');
  else alert('Массив имеет отрицательные и положительные элементы')
}

checkArray([4, 3, 2, 6, 7]);
checkArray([-4, -3, -2, -6, -7]);
checkArray([-4, -3, 2, 6, 7]);
```